# MVC 3 - parse FormCollection to model

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, collections

For my sample application I am building I am currently forced to pass a FormCollection object into my action method when attempting to do ajax updates on my view.

The reason I have chosen to pass FormCollection is that my view is rather complex and contains nested collections. If I were to Serialize and Json.Stringify it drops these nested collections when passed into my action method.

Is there a good technique to map my FormCollection object to an instance of my ViewModel once inside the controller ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TryUpdateModel<TypeOfYourModel>(YourModelInstance)`